# How to calculate numbers in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such string `13-2-10-7-3` where numbers delimited by `-`.

I am wondering what is the best way to calculate the `sum` of all numbers from the string in javascript?

Comment: Split by dash, map numbers, then reduce with sum.

Comment: For reference: [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function which will split your string by the `-`. Then go through all the results and add them.

```
function add(string){ 
    return string.split('-').reduce(function(a,b){return+a+(+b); });  
}
```

This will use a regex to extract the numbers from the string. Then it will add them using `.reduce()`. not to complicated. The `+a+(+b)` will convert `a` and `b` to JavaScript numbers and then add them. `+var` will make a variable from a string to a number. This is the shortest method you could achieve as far as I know.

If you can't support the `.reduce()` function, use the alternate code which should support every browser:

```
function add(string) {
    var strings = string.split('-'),
        sum = 0,i;
    for (i = 0; i < strings.length; i +=1 ) {
        sum += (+strings[i]);
    }
}
```

**SPEED: ~0.062 seconds**

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/blue1086/9yxd6b1r/)

Answer (score 1):

Since the numbers are always separated by `-` then the best approach is to **split** them into an array:

[About string's split method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
var string = '13-2-10-7-3';
numbers = string.split('-');
```

At this points `numbers` will be a array of strings, you can't sum them up yet or else you will just concatenate them together. So you should convert them to number.

This is easily done **mapping** the array elements to numbers

[About array's map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap)

```js
numbers = numbers.map(Number);
```

Now you can **reduce** the array to the sum of its elements

[About array's reduce method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var result = numbers.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; });
```

All at once:

```js
var string = '13-2-10-7-3';
var numbers = string.split('-').map(Number);
var sum = numbers.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = "13-2-10-7-3".split('-').reduce(function(x, y) {
    return parseInt(x)+ parseInt(y);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

The "split" function turns the delimitedNumbers string into an array of strings. Using the "-" to determine where to split.

Conceptually, the numbers variable would look like ["13"]["2"]["10"]["7"]["3"] after the split.

We then loop through the numbers array, using the parseInt function to convert each element from a string to a number and then add to the current value of the sum variable.

Finally we summon an alert pop-up to display the final sum.

```
  sum = function(){
    var i, len, delimitedNumbers, numbers, sum;

    delimitedNumbers = "13-2-10-7-3";

    numbers = delimitedNumbers.split('-');
    len = numbers.length;

    sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + parseInt(numbers[i]);
    }

    alert("The sum is: " + sum);
  }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oLrqoyon/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`reduce()` requires IE9+

I'm using `jQuery.each` here

```js
var input = '13-2-10-7-3', sum = 0;


$.each(input.split('-'), function(idx, elm) {
  sum += (+elm); // parse string to int using `+` 
});

document.write('The sum of ' + input + ' is ' + sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Adding jQuery seems overkill for adding numbers

Comment: the OP tagged `jQuery`, I would assume he uses jQuery