# Multiply numbers in string with JS

Tags: javascript

I have this string:

```
var sting = "500*500*500";
```

Now i'd like to calculate the numbers in the string just as they are.

If i just had the numbers outside the string i could do math like:

```
var sum = 500*500*500;
console.log(sum) will return: 125000000
```

I found this question:
[How to calculate numbers in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503603/how-to-calculate-numbers-in-string)

Isn't there a easier way?
Like:

```
var sum = calc(string);
```

Comment: `eval(string)` can be used in this case.

Comment: Is three lines of code really too difficult? You could do `eval()` if you're 110% sure what you're doing and what the implications are.

Comment: @JJJ Of corse not to difficult, just unnnnessesary... much code.

Comment: Apparently a 112kb library isn't too much code then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use a Mathematic specialised eval function.

Make your own or simply use the awesome [MathJS](http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html)

```
// evaluate expressions
math.eval('sqrt(3^2 + 4^2)');           // 5
math.eval('sqrt(-4)');                  // 2i
math.eval('2 inch to cm');              // 5.08 cm
math.eval('cos(45 deg)');               // 0.7071067811865476
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://mathjs.org/ 
IE:

```
print(math.eval('500*500*500'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(
  '500*500*500'
    .split('*') // => ['500', '500', '500']
    .reduce((product, number) => product * number, 1)
)
```